# web services heterogeneous system support

Tags: web-services

I am zero in webservices so this is my endeavour in picking it up 
Have started with some basics - but one question that comes to mind is :
If I am exposing a web service written in Java - that has a simple method - which returns an Employee Object - now on the consumer side of the web service - lets say I am a .NET consumer - and since this webservice returns an Employee object - how is this represented in .NET ?
who takes care of this ?

NOTE - I am a Java developer so havent dabbled in other languages - but just wanted to know

Thanks,
satish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client which is consuming the web service has to know about the type of object. It can deserialize the stream if it has info about the type of recieving object. You can publish object schema through WSDL. The .NET client can take this WSDL and generate class according to schema.